# How to programmatically turn off quirks mode in IE8 WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, webbrowser-control, standards-compliance, quirks-mode

I want to use IE8 as a WebBrowser control in a C# application.  How can I disable "quirks mode" and force IE into standards compliance (as far as it is implemented)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the issue you're facing is described in [IEBlog: WebBrowser Control Rendering Modes in IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx):

> While webmasters can easily alter
>   their site to render properly in the
>   new version of IE, many software
>   vendors do not have the resources to
>   instantly push out new versions of
>   their applications with updated
>   internal pages.
>   In order to ensure that these existing
>   applications remain in working order,
>   **IE8 renders pages running within
>   instances of the WebBrowser control in
>   IE7 Standards Mode by default.**

Here I should note that the comments on the page say the above is incorrect, and that "**IE8 renders pages running within instances of the WebBrowser control in IE7 Strict Mode OR Quirks mode by default**, depending on the page's doctype."

The solution is as follows:

> When an executable loads an instance
>   of the WebBrowser control it scans the
>   registry to check whether the
>   executable wants IE7 Standards or IE8
>   Standards mode.
>
> ...
>
> To run in IE8 Standards Mode insert
>   the following registry value:
>
> `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_NATIVE_DOCUMENT_MODE]`
>
> `"MyApplication.exe"=dword:13880`
>
> In both of these instances,
>   MyApplication.exe should be replaced
>   with the name of the executable that
>   will be running WebBrowser controls in
>   a specified mode.

So it sounds like the "programmatic" solution is to write a key in the registry saying you want IE8 Standards mode for `WebBrowser` controls in your specific application.

Comment: It would be better if there was a property to set on the browser control - this would be easer when the user does not have registry permissions, though this is less of an issue under HKEY_CURRENT_USER (the key also works in the equivalent point under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).

Comment: FYI, `FEATURE_NATIVE_DOCUMENT_MODE` has been superceeded by `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`.

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want to use the registry key technique, you could insert the following tag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

The "content" attribute forces rendering in various modes.

Comment: The above tag was striped from my post.  Just add the opening angle bracket.

Comment: Just surround your meta tag with backticks, like this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>`.

Comment: I think the question was really how to force the browser itself (he's using a asp.net WebBrowser control to "create" a browser in his application). Changing this meta parameter or the doc type (which is the usual solution - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) is something that you do at the site level... What is explained by Daniel is how to override any site's setting to a standard non-quirks mode. I think this was properly explained by Daniel.

Comment: My experience is that there are subtle differences: using the Registry way, IE8 embedded is just like IE8. Using the meta tag, there is still some IE7-ish rendering.

Comment: @Elijah I must ask, is this the one and only, Elijah Manor?

Answer (score 4):

The last I heard was that IE8 would use [standards mode by default](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/03/microsoft-s-interoperability-principles-and-ie8.aspx). Are you seeing an actual problem with the latest beta version? Are you sure it's rendering in quirks mode to start with, without a user explicitly hitting the [compatibility view button](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/12/03/compatibility-view-improvements-to-come-in-ie8.aspx)?

Comment: I think the `WebBrowser` control and the standalone browser behave differently in this case.

Comment: Looks like it, yes. Will edit question title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Please note there have been some changes since the beta, the registry keys have been renamed etc.  [Read more here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This has actual code to programmatically do this and handles up to IE11 so far:

[C# webbrowser Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/20848398#20848398)