# How to disable compatibility view settings?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, compatibility

I've been trying to load a specific page on a web browser control that works fine with the installed IE on my system, but I keep getting a message box (created by the page) that I have to disable the compatibility view. The same page works fine on my IE 9.0 without tampering with the settings. I can't get it!
The same thing happens if I use gecko and I can't figure out why...
Is there any way to disable the settings programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/20848398#20848398 has the programmatic code you desire, but by now no longer need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) is what you need. There are other discussions about similar issues on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646742/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-quirks-mode-in-ie8-webbrowser-control). I think the only way to change the settings programmatically would be to edit the registry with code.

Comment: The first two links don't answer: "Why does it act differently in IE and the WebBrowser control?" The 3rd looks more promising (and perhaps is a "duplicate").

Comment: @pst, It attempts to answer the question "How do I disable compatibility mode for the webbrowser control." Is that not what the OP was after?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping for a more programmatic solution, without registry or html changes.

Comment: @user1426332, I can relate. I ran into a huge mess of unexpected compatibility problems on a recent project that used a WebBrowser control. Adding a registry key was the only solution I could find. :\

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the this msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It should help with your problem

Comment: This doesn't answer: "Why does it act differently in IE and the WebBrowser control?"

Comment: @pst, Was that the question the OP was asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a META tag in your page that will force it to display in the format you want.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

See this MSDN article for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `content="IE=Edge"` worked for me with <meta> being the first item inside <head>