# C# WebBrowser Ajax call

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using a WebBrowser control embedded in a C# WPF .NET4 app. Whenever I press manually the button in a form, the browser hangs on "Your request is being processed" message and nothing happens. If I do the same in full IE browser, the page is processed normally producing the results.
What am I missing?

The code behind the button:

```xml
<a onclick="startSearch();" href="javascript:void(-1);" name="btnNext" class="btn floatLe noClear btnSubmit btnRight"> 
<span>Continue</span> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

WebBrowser control (both WPF and WinForms versions) behaves in many ways differently from the full IE. You may want to implement [Feature Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to bring its behavior as close to IE as possible (particularly, `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`), this often solves the script compatibility issues. Here is some code, note that it **does not require admin rights** to run:

```
private void SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(string feature, string appName, uint value)
{
    using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
        String.Concat(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\", feature), 
        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
    {
        key.SetValue(appName, (UInt32)value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
private void SetBrowserFeatureControl()
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

    // FeatureControl settings are per-process
    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

    // make the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
    if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0 || String.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0) 
        return;

    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", fileName, GetBrowserEmulationMode()); // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE ", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING ", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI  ", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS ", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_XMLHTTP", fileName, 1);
}

private UInt32 GetBrowserEmulationMode()
{
    int browserVersion = 7;
    using (var ieKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer",
        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree,
        System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.QueryValues))
    {
        var version = ieKey.GetValue("svcVersion");
        if (null == version)
        {
            version = ieKey.GetValue("Version");
            if (null == version)
                throw new ApplicationException("Microsoft Internet Explorer is required!");
        }
        int.TryParse(version.ToString().Split('.')[0], out browserVersion);
    }

    UInt32 mode = 11000; // Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 11.
    switch (browserVersion)
    {
        case 7:
            mode = 7000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.
            break;
        case 8:
            mode = 8000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
            break;
        case 9:
            mode = 9000; // Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
            break;
        case 10:
            mode = 10000; // Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
            break;
        default:
            // use IE11 mode by default
            break;
    }

    return mode;
}
```

You should come up with your own [set of features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and register them before WebBrowser has initialized, e.g., in the main form constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    SetBrowserFeatureControl();

    InitializeComponent();
//...
}
```

**Updated**, I currently use and recommend a set of features that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/1768303).

Comment: @Jim, I've added a check for "XDesProc.exe" (VS XAML Designer process), you may want to update your code too.

Comment: I am not sure if I can continue this thread, but the page I am working on has also an Ajax Popup window which again is not showing in IE embedded browser, but in out of application it works fine?

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell what's causing it, but I'd again go through the list of [all available options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and play with those which look related, trying both 1 and 0 values. E.g., FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS, FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT, FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS, FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING etc. Let us know if you find it :)

Comment: @Noseratio: Great code. Thank you. FYI: `SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE", fileName, 0)` blocks setting mouse cursor by mouse-clicking inside WebBrowser control navigated web pages' text boxes. Windows 8. IE10.0.9200.16750, update: 10.0.12

Comment: @ShamilS, thank you, good point, I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: No way to do this without reg-edits? This amounts to an ugly hack IMHO. Not a viable solution for me (production machines are locked down).

Comment: @FizxMike, so locked down that even writing under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is not possible? You don't need `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` for this.

Comment: I ended up using CEFSharp for my browser window instead.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:`yourWebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`