# C# WebBrowser component ignores window.location.href = url

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make asp.net mvc application to be shown in c# webbrowser component. Everything works fine except file downloading.
In this mvc application there is a lot of side components, so there was found no other way to handle downloadFileLink but to use following JS:

```
function downloadButtonClick(s, e, buttonID, actionUrl) {
    var downloadUrl = actionUrl + '?FileID=' + s.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex);
    if (e.buttonID == buttonID) {
        window.location = downloadUrl;
    }
}
```

this approach works fine while I'm trying to download file by this link using any browser, except webbrowser component.
It seems to ignore all `window.location` manipulations(I've tried `window.location.href = downloadUrl` and `window.location.replace(downloadUrl)`)

Can anyone give a reason to this behavior?

Comment: Does it work in the full IE browser? If so, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982).

Comment: Yes,that solution works perfectly. Probably someone could format it as an answer?

Comment: Glad it solved the problem. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your web page doesn't work properly in WebBrowser control, but does well in the full Internet Explorer browser, consider [implementing Feature Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303).