# IE WebBrowser not sending some redrawing messages

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, webbrowser-control, atl

I have a property sheet view with few property pages. One of this property page contains a HTML representation via a CHtmlView derived class.

Initially, the .html file is correctly rendered. The problem is that sometimes switching between properties pages sometime the html file is not redraw. The behavior appears randomly.
According to Spy++ in such situation some Windows messages are not sent by WebControl (**Internet Explorer_Server** layer): WM_ERASEBKGRD, WM_PAINT or WM_NCPAINT.

Approaches such [Q179421](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179421) or [Q183161](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183161) are not useful. My machine runs IE 10.
The windows hierarchy is: Shell Embedding -> Shell DocObject View -> Internet Explorer_Server.

Do you know any workaround that would determine Internet Explorer_Server layer to send these messages always?

Update: Even if in the real application I make some intensive processing, I was able to reproduce this bug even with a dummy Html content.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18383548/1768303). Shouldn't be a problem to covert it from C# to C++.

Comment: The issue was fixed with a workaround. The problem was that sometimes the view representation was not completely created or the expected messages came before my HtmlView’s data population notification. That’s why I used a timer of few milliseconds to let once the update of data representation. I didn’t use additional thread because of simplicity (I’m working with COM internally).