# show asp menu in c# webbrowser

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control, aspmenu

I have developed a web browser in c# using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
But it doesn't show "asp:Menu" items at my pages.
I've use this code in my asp project:

```
 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="default"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Exit.aspx" Text="exit"/>
                   <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Setting.aspx" Text="setting"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

also I've used more web browser sources downloaded from codeproject.com like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60179/Web-Browser-in-C

Comment: What does not work: your page or "your" browser?

Comment: The browser does not show menu Items

Comment: I got that, what I mean: does your browser show other web pages correctly or does your page show up correctly with other browsers?

Comment: yes, my page is correctly shown by other browsers such as IE, Mozila fireFox and Google Chrome, and my browser shows other pages correctly. reRealy I don't know if the prblem is related to my browser or my asp page.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your page works in other browsers but not in `WebBrowser` control. If so, try implementing [WebBrowser Feature Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982).

**[EDITED]** Once you've implemented `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`, if you want the standard rendering mode with the latest HTML5 features for `WebBrowser`, the following markup will enable it for your page:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
<!-- cutting edge rendering --> 
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is on your browser. I try your code, and it shown correctly.