# Change IE mode for Webbrowser control

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, ie8-browser-mode

I have IE10 installed on my machine and am trying to access a web application which I do not own. I am trying to embed a URL of that web application in .net browser control in my desktop application. The web application URL loads fine when I change the document mode of IE to either IE8 or IE9 standards, but fails to load in the default IE7 standards mode. I would like to be able force the web-browser control to run IE in IE8 or IE9 standards mode programatically in my .net application. I googled a lot & most of the solutions I found talked about the following two approaches.

1. Making a registry entry to force IE to emulate a particular mode for my application.
2. Adding the META tag to the HTML page to force it to open in a particular mode.

Is there any other suggested approach for this ? Earlier, I remember I could increase max connections (of IE) per server using wininet setInternetOption API. Is there any such API to set the IE mode for my application ? I would very much appreciate if someone can point me to some code snippet for the same.

Comment: A similar question [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18483398/1768303).

Comment: The approach I am looking for is not to make an actual registry entry. The problem with registry editing is, the logged in user should have admin privilege. If my desktop application is run on non-admin user account, I still want the browser emulation to be enforced.

Comment: Have you checked the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982)? Everything is done inside `Registry.CurrentUser` during runtime, no admin rights needed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the registry as it runs in compatibility mode of the version you have installed natively. Refer to the below link.

[Will the IE9 WebBrowser Control Support all of IE9's features, including SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)