# Why is InternetExplorerClass ReadyState = tagREADYSTATE_COMPLETE not working? any alternatives?

Tags: c#, multithreading, internet-explorer

When I call _InternetExplorer.Navigate(....) and just Thread.Sleep() for 10 seconds, the program works fine. The IE object navigates correctly and I can save the InternetExlorerClass.Document as HTMLDocument. I am trying to make the proccess as quick as possible though. I am trying to use the events, such as DocumentComplete to my advantage. If I try to use DocumentComplete and the ReadyState property to call upon a function that saves the HTMLDocument this never works. The InternetExplorer.Document and the saved HTMLDocument is always incomplete. Why is that? any help would be nice!

```
public void ThreadPoolCallback(Object threadContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("launching {0} Scraping...", threadContext.ToString());

        _InternetExplorerObject.BeforeNavigate2 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(BeforeNavigate2);
        _InternetExplorerObject.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(DocumentComplete);
        _InternetExplorerObject.NavigateError += new DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateErrorEventHandler(NavigateError);

        _InternetExplorerObject.Navigate(_URL, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    }
    public void IE_SaveObjectAsHTML()
    {
        MyHTMLdoc = _InternetExplorerObject.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass;
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("The HTML Doc has saved");
        _DoneEvent.Set();
        _InternetExplorerObject.Quit();
    }


    private void BeforeNavigate2(object sender, ref object URL, ref object Flags, ref object Target, ref object PostData, ref object Headers, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Navigation Initiated");
    }
    private void DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Website Loaded");
        while (_InternetExplorerObject.ReadyState != tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Ready State Reached");
        IE_SaveObjectAsHTML();
    }
    private void NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Target, ref object StatusCode, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR : Navigation Failed. Refreshing");
        _InternetExplorerObject.Refresh();
        return;
    }




    public HTMLDocumentClass get_IE()
    {
        return MyHTMLdoc;
    }




    private System.Threading.EventWaitHandle myWaitHandle = new System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(false, System.Threading.EventResetMode.ManualReset);
    private string _URL;
    private InternetExplorer _InternetExplorerObject = new InternetExplorerClass();
    private object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    private Type IEType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application");
    private ManualResetEvent _DoneEvent;
    private HTMLDocumentClass MyHTMLdoc;
```

Comment: You are violating STA threading requirements, you are not allowed to block the UI thread.  IE cannot update the Ready property until your UI thread goes idle and re-enters the message loop.  Your thread isn't idle, it is stuck in the loop.  Just delete the code, the DocumentCompleted event is already good enough to tell you that the document load is completed.

Comment: So you are saying the loop inside DocumentComplete is not allowing the IE object to continue to readystate_complete?

Comment: and should I also remove the IE_SaveObjectAsHTML() from DocumentComplete? if so where should I be putting it?

Comment: @kennedy484, indeed, you should not block the thread inside event handler, there are ways of doing this asynchronously. What is the execution environment of your app (WinForms, WPF, Console, etc)? Also, are you aware of this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18458398/1768303 ?

Comment: I am executing this in a console application. should I not be calling a function from an event handler, will that also cause the IE object to block?