# .NET COM Interop -> Global exception handler

Tags: .net, delphi, com

I have a .NET assembly which is invoked via COM Interop from a Delphi Host.
I understand that any unhandled exception in the .NET code will be handled by the .net com interop framework and a correspoding HRESULT will be returned to the the COM host (delphi). Stack information is however lost during this Exception to HRESULT conversion.

The problem is that we would like to log all unhandled exceptions in .net code and I have not found any way to register a catch-all handler that is actually invoked whenever such an exception occurs.

I have tried:

- AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
- Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException

but these are not invoked when running under COM Interop.

Is it possible to define some sort of handler/callback for unhandled exceptions for the COM Interop Framework? Or somehow hook into the process of converting a Managed Exception to an HRESULT so that the exception can be logged?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you best bet would be to use something like `try { .. } catch (Exception ex) { /* save ex*/; throw; }` everywhere in your C# methods exposed to COM. Alternatively, you could handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` and store the last 1st-chance exception, which you could also expose to COM.

Comment: @Noseratio your suggestion works. I have found no better approach. You should add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Noseratio unfortunately the better approach you propose does not work in my situation. This is however due to a flaw in Delphi. See comments to your answer.
I ended up defining the handler for the FirstChanceExceptions and storing the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best option here would be to use something like

```cs
void ComClassMethod()
{
    try { ... } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        /* store the ex in the object */; 
        throw; 
    } 
}
```

everywhere in your C# methods exposed to COM.

Alternatively, you could handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` and store the last 1st-chance exception, which you could also expose to COM.

However, pay special attention if your COM object support muliti-hreading (note, most .NET COM [objects are free-threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28628811/1768303)). In this case, you'd need to maintain a map between threads and their corresponding most-recent exceptions, either per object or globally via `System.Threading.ThreadLocal<T>` (decide what suits your logging requirements better).

---

**Updated**, I've been thinking, there has to be a better way of doing this. And there is one, indeed, as [explained here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=x2OIPSyFLBcC&lpg=PT609&ots=_qtEVH3SnZ&pg=PT609#v=onepage&f=false) in Adam Nathan's excellent ".NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide" book. I'm not sure I can copy/paste an exact quote from the copyrighted material, but the idea is the following:

- All .NET CCW objects implement `ISupportErrorInfo`.
- The extended error information - via an [`IErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object - can be retrieved on COM side via [`GetErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.
- According to Adam Nathan, this object also *is the .NET exception object itself*, and it implements the [`_Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception(v=vs.90).aspx) COM interface.
- The COM client can use `_Exception` to get all the details, including [`_Exception.StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices._exception.stacktrace(v=vs.90).aspx).

This seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: when using the SafeCall convention, Delphi will automatically call GetErrorInfo and raise a delphi Exception of type EOleException which is populated with the values from the retrieved IErrorInfo object. Unfortunately the EOleException does not hold any reference to the IErrorInfo object.
If I understand the GetErrorInfo doc. correctly:
"
It transfers ownership of the error object to the caller, and clears the error state for the thread.
"
this means the ErrorInfo object is no longer available when calling GetErrorInfo after Delphi has done its 'magic'.

Comment: Ran out of space on the previous comment.
When I subsequently call, GetErrorInfo I can no longer retrieve the IErrorInfo object. It is lost forever....

Comment: @santiagoIT, I see. My Delphi knowledges are quite limited, but I remember it's possible to use raw COM interfaces generated from the typelib, without smart wrappers. I understand this might not be an option for you.