# Open hidden internet explorer using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I saw that many people asked this question but it just does not work for me!

```
try
{                      
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = Url.ToString();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
catch (Win32Exception ex)
{
    var err = ex.ToString();
}
```

It still opens the browser !
anybody can say why?

Comment: Use [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) to download from a URL in the background without creating a window.

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the idea...
but i would like to know why the code still opens the IE?
i saw on MSDN the same code, but somehow it still opens the browser for me.
can you see why?

Comment: is your goal to know why? or to know how to get a hidden IE window?

Comment: Can you comment the MSDN link?

Comment: first of all i need to get the hidden explorer.
and second i have to understand why it doesnt work, im working on it 2 days and i have to understand where do i get wrong??
it makes me frustrated....

Comment: [There's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402342/start-hidden-internet-explorer) a [bunch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427324/handle-ie-to-filling-a-form-c-sharp/18427724#18427724) of [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133531/opening-a-hidden-internet-explorer-window-without-it-getting-focus) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427324/handle-ie-to-filling-a-form-c-sharp/18427724#18427724) on SO about this. I'd try one of those.

Comment: @Brandon 
here is one of the articles from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx)
its about the CreateNoWindow.
ill check about the
    ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

Comment: CreateNoWindow is only for console apps. Apparently IE is not a console application.