# HtmlElement doesn't parse the tag properly

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I have the following line in my html source:

```
<input class="phone" name="site_url" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Website URL">
```

When I navigate using WebBrowser Control (C#) and load my site to an HtmlDocument object, and then loop over each HtmlElement, when I get to the input element above:

I can't get the placeholder attribute. GetAttribute("placeholder") returns "".
I checked the OuterHtml/InnerHtml fields and noted that placeholder attribute is copied with "" while other attributes are not, moreover, I can retrieve other attributes (name, class).

This is the output of InnerHtml/OuterHtml:

```
<INPUT class=phone placeholder="Enter Your Website URL" name=site_url>
```

Can anybody explain why is that and how can I change placeholder in this case?

Comment: What exactly you have in your source (check with view-source): `placeholder="Enter Your Website URL"` or `placeholder=**"**Enter Your Website URL**"**` ?

Comment: the first, the ** is for bolding the text (<b>).

Comment: I see, I'd suggest editing your question and removing those stars, you cannot use bold inside the code.

Comment: reread it now, i think you misunderstood me. ** aren't part of the code. it is exactly how it looks like now. the problem is that only placeholder attribute has double quotes

Comment: I meant to remove the stars from the code fragment you originally posted as part of your question. You did just that - awesome, now it's easier for someone to try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `WebBrowser` control runs in IE7 compatibility mode. In that mode, `placeholder` attribute is not supported. Thus, first you need to switch it into IE10 mode, [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982). Then, you would need to call unmanaged [getAttributeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536430(v=vs.85).aspx) and get its `value`, here's how:

```
bool FindElementWithPlaceholder(HtmlElement root, string placeholder, ref HtmlElement found, ref string value)
{
    foreach (var child in root.Children)
    {
        var childElement = (HtmlElement)child;
        dynamic domElement = childElement.DomElement;
        dynamic attrNode = domElement.getAttributeNode(placeholder);
        if (attrNode != null)
        {
            string v = attrNode.value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v))
            {
                value = v;
                found = childElement;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (FindElementWithPlaceholder(childElement, placeholder, ref found, ref value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// ...

HtmlElement element = null;
string value = null;
if (FindElementWithPlaceholder(this.WB.Document.Body, "placeholder", ref element, ref value))
    MessageBox.Show(value);
```

This code has been tested with IE10.

**[EDITED]** You can still retrieve the value of `placeholder` with the above code, even if [WebBrowser Feature Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982) is not emplemented. However, `placeholder` won't function visually in such case, because the document won't be in HTML5 mode.

**[EDITED]** Perhaps, I finally understand what you want. Try this code and see if it does that. You still need the Feature Control and DOCTYPE to enable HTML5.

```
HTML: <!doctype html><html><input class=phone placeholder=\"Enter Your Website URL\" name=site_url></html>

HtmlElement element = null;
string oldValue = null;
string newValue = "New Value";
FindElementWithPlaceholder(this.webBrowser1.Document.Body, "placeholder", ref element, ref value, newValue);

bool FindElementWithPlaceholder(HtmlElement root, string placeholder, ref HtmlElement found, ref string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    foreach (var child in root.Children)
    {
        var childElement = (HtmlElement)child;
        dynamic domElement = childElement.DomElement;
        dynamic attrNode = domElement.getAttributeNode(placeholder);
        if (attrNode != null)
        {
            string v = attrNode.value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v))
            {
                domElement.removeAttributeNode(attrNode);
                domElement.setAttribute(placeholder, newValue);
                // a hack to make IE10 to render the new placeholder  
                var id = domElement.getAttribute("id");
                var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                domElement.setAttribute("id", uniqueId);
                var html = domElement.outerHTML;
                domElement.outerHTML = html;
                var newElement = root.Document.GetElementById(uniqueId);
                domElement = newElement.DomElement;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
                    domElement.removeAttribute("id");
                else
                    domElement.setAttribute("id", id);
                found = newElement;
                oldValue = v;
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (FindElementWithPlaceholder(childElement, placeholder, ref found, ref oldValue, newValue))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This prints the value of placholder (e.g. "Enter your WebSite URL") - my whole point is to change it programmatically by SetAttribute and then Invoke a "click" to have my own input instead of "Enter your website URL". How does this answer help me?

Comment: Well, perhaps then you should edit the title of your question *HtmlElement doesn't parse the tag properly* and its content *I can't get the placeholder attribute.* Did my answer address that, at least?

Comment: That said, if you just add the following  `((dynamic)element.DomElement).value = "New Value"` next to `MessageBox`, it will do what you need, if that's the whole point of it.

Answer (score 1):

> HtmlElement exposes only those attributes that are common to all elements, leaving out those that only apply to certain types of elements;

[HtmlElement.GetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute.aspx) is identical to IHTMLElement::getAttribute(strAttributeName, 0)

There are some change on how [getAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is working related to Internet Explorer 8, check Remarks section. To resolve this you can do manual parsing for InnerHtml to extract that custom placeholder attribute.

Comment: I need to change the text and submit the form. Do you mean to replace strings? if yes, what should I change (InnerHtml? OutHtml? the Body?) so if I call InvokeMember the form will be posted with the new text?

Comment: You can use HtmlElement.SetAttribute for that. Find element by name site_url and set attribute value by using el.SetAttribute("placeholder", "new value")

Comment: this will add a new placeholder ignoring the existing. not sure if that's what i want