# Reading "aria-label" via MSHTML returns NULL

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, mshtml

I'm trying to read an HTML element's *aria-label* attribute using IE's [`getAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752280.aspx) method in C++/COM but although this works fine for other attributes (including *aria-labelledby*) it returns VT_NULL for *aria-label*.

My code example looks like this:

```
CComVariant label;
elem->raw_getAttribute(CComBSTR(L"aria-label"), 0, &label);
if (label.vt == VT_BSTR && SysStringLen(label.bstrVal)) {
    // This is never reached
}
```

I get the same results when using 2 for the `flags` argument of `getAttribute`.

Sample [HTML here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Uzp/1/).

When I try using `getAttribute` in JavaScript in the browser this works perfectly but for some reason I can't reach this attribute using COM.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try `getAttributeNode`. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18450660/1768303

Comment: Thanks @Noseratio, this works, please consider adding this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, some new new HTML5 attributes are accessible via DOM Level 3 [`getAttributeNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536430(v=vs.85).aspx) method (available in `IHTMLElement4`).

E.g., to make it work for [`placeholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute, I had to use [WebBrowser Feature Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303) and enable HTML5 for the web page with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` (which is a good idea in either case).