# MFC Web Browser Control app behaves different than IE9

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control

I have some site that behaves deferentially in MFC Browser Control then in real IE9.
I have created a simple MFC browser control application in VS 2010 according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcbhy332%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I have changed the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION [registry flag](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) to be 9999 for this application.

Now, try to browse to www.cvc.com.br --> fill in from/to and dates --> press "Buscar"
In IE9 it will navigate to the search results page, in MFC application it will do nothing.

Kindly advise, what else should be done to make IE9 identical to the MFC application.

Thanks in advance,
G

Comment: There are other features besides `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982).

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped! However, I added all of the flags in the link and wonder which did the trick? is there any combination did it? and if there is a bad influence on my application according to it.

Comment: That was just a sample set of feature flags. You should carefully go through each [feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx) and come up with your own set that works for you. If the linked answer helped, feel free to up-vote it.

Comment: @Noseratio - I already up-voted you.

Comment: Thank you. Did you find what specific feature caused problem for MFC Browser Control?

Comment: @Noseratio - Not yet.

Comment: Guy, then you may want to keep an eye on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18576963/1768303).