# using meta tag "X-UA-Compatible"

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, c#-4.0

I came across multiple blogs about using meta tag to change rendering mode/version of internet explore as IE9 or 10 are combination of multiple browsers.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"`>

But for me this tag seems to be working only in full Internet explorer browser only, but not in .net browser control. Am I correct in my observation?

I have to override default browser version (from 7 to 8) picked by browser control. Changing/adding registry parameter is not an option.

Comment: Why exactly is "adding registry parameter" (specifically `Feature_Browser_Emulation`) not possible? That's the proper way to fix this.

Comment: EricLaw, adding registry parameter is possible but not an option, customer don't want any kind of manipulation in registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the `X-UA-Compatible` value via the META tag or HTTP response header, the **document mode** will change to the value specified, just like in Desktop IE.

Unlike changing the **browser mode** using the F12 Developer Tools, the **document mode** does not impact the `User-Agent` string sent to the server. In fully-patched versions of IE, the `X-UA-Compatible` setting does impact the `User-Agent` shown to JavaScript in the `navigator.userAgent` property, although that value is unchanged if the `document mode` setting is changed using the F12 developer tools.

You can explore the results of sending `X-UA-Compatible` by viewing

http://webdbg.com/ua.aspx

and

http://webdbg.com/ua9.aspx

The first page does not specify a document mode (and thus gets the default) while the latter specifies the document mode is IE9. If you click the **Document mode** link, you can see that the document's mode is sensitive to the `X-UA-Compatible` directive, even if the User-Agent in the request headers is unchanged.

In contrast, to change the **browser mode** of the Web Browser control within your application, you must set the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` registry key, specifying the name of your executable and the desired mode.

A customer requirement that "no registry changes may be made" is goofy. It's reasonable to say: "We don't want any registry manipulation *that would impact IE or another program*." It's unreasonable to say: "We don't want any registry manipulation at all" considering that the mere act of running your executable results in changes to the registry.

Comment: +1 and @Manish, you don't need admin rights to the registry for this to work, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive is enough, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303).

Comment: I found this false. Setting the X-UA-Compatible to IE8 does render an IE8 user agent if you access it via JS navigator.userAgent (not server side)

Comment: @ShaneN: I've clarified this answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This meta tag works correctly only if this is the first element in the `<head>` section.

Comment: tpolyak, have you ever tried this, as meta tag doesn't seems to be working for me in .net web browser control, it only works in Internet explorer browser. Meta tag is a very first line in `<HEAD`>