# Allowing scripts to run in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, webbrowser-control

I am trying to build a support platform for my company and I have gotten everything to work except a web based tool that is loaded from our web host into a webbrowser component. I am able to get the webpage to load but it seem that the visual studio application is not allowing scripts to run. The site throws a script every time I click a button that calls a script. Any Ideas?

Some Info: 
I am using visual studio 2012
The sites works in IE without issue

-kinda new, let me know if you need more info- 
[image]

Comment: I get DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER-ERR (5) When the script tries to load. I need the script to load and it does using any other browser. Just not the one in visual studio.

Comment: What is the context? What program is showing that dialog? Is it your own program, or is it Visual Studio itself? If it's your program, then show the code that initializes the WebBrowser control. Also, say whether it is a Windows Forms program or a WPF program.

Comment: It is a windows forms and it seems like it is the application that I made, but it is localized to the script running in the webbrowser component from the web page. http://youtu.be/fNQvJiCDLRw

Comment: You say it worked in IE, but try that with the F12 Developer Tools turned on so you can see warnings in the console window. Also, show the code you use to init the control.

Comment: @JakeFischer, consider implementing WebBrowser [feature control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982).