# WebBrowser control leaks memory specifically when handling Click events

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control, handle-leak

I am in Windows 7, .NET 4.5, IE10.  I have a simple windows form application with a `WebBrowser` control. Every time the page navigates, I want to add a click handler. I notice that memory is leaking when I do this. I am in fact detaching the event handlers and so am confused as to why memory is leaking.

I noticed that I can attach to the `HtmlDocument.Click` event and do not see the leaks associated with `HtmlElement.Click`. This is demonstrated in the program below that periodically navigates using a timer.

Also of interest is that the URL does seem to matter... e.g. I see the problem with http://www.google.com but not with http://thin.npr.org (or about:blank). This would lead me to believe that at the core this is a javascript problem, but then the "fix" I am currently employing (see below) doesn't really have anything to do with javascript...

So what is causing the problem and how do I work around the issues so my program does not leak memory/handles?

My current "fix" is to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on the `HtmlElement.DomElement` property.  Is this a correct thing to do? Shouldn't `HtmlElement` clean up after itself, like `HtmlDocument` apparently does? Should I expect problems with other classes in addition to `HtmlElement`?

I'm tempted to sprinkle `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` generously anywhere that I see a com object (and not assume the containing class will properly do so). Is that a safe thing to do?

My complete program follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer t;
        WebBrowser webBrowser;

        public Form1()
        {
            webBrowser = new WebBrowser 
            { 
               Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
               Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com/")
            };
            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
            this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);

            t = new Timer { Interval = 2000 };
            t.Tick += t_Tick;
        }

        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Stop();
            webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
        }

        void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (webBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                var doc = webBrowser.Document;
                if (doc == null) //no page loaded
                    return;

                //the following two lines do not cause a leak
                doc.Click += click_handler;
                doc.Click -= click_handler;

                var body = doc.Body;

                if (body != null)
                {
                    //the following 2 lines cause memory and handle leaks
                    body.Click += click_handler;
                    body.Click -= click_handler;

                    //uncommenting the following line appears to fix the leak
                    //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(body.DomElement);

                    body = null;
                }

                GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
                t.Start();
            }
        }

        void click_handler(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

For anyone curious, I did a test using a `WeakReference` to the `body` object in my program and verified that it IS being garbage collected.

After running the "Fixed" version for some time (maybe an hour), it is steady at ~40 megs of private bytes, and 640 handles. The "leaky" version gets up to hundreds of megs and thousands of handles, and does not appear to be slowing down. In production a user had a process using over 900 megs when things stopped functioning (images wouldn't load). Closing the application took several seconds to tear everything down.

Comment: Try implementing `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` and `FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS` [WebBrowser features](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303) and see if it makes any difference (just an idea).

Comment: I implemented every feature I could think of and this doesn't appear to have an effect! Still glad for the information, it fixed a completely unrelated problem :)

Comment: The `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` "fix" mentioned in the question has been working for several users in production for a couple of days now. I'm tempted to say it's a solved issue ... still seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS! Handles will be released immediately after closing the webbrowser. USE CODE:

```
using system.windows.forms;
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr pProcess, int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

// **Release handles invoking the above**
IntPtr pHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1);
```

Happy coding!