# WebBrowser local html file, flash not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using a WinForm webbrowser, i load an local html file which contains and flash player that plays a video but the problem is that the player works but the video is not loaded.

When i open the html file in a browser it works fine.

Here is the code i am using:

```
        string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/Resources/streaming.html", curDir));
```

The file location is correct, is there anything i can do to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly disabling the following [Browser Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for your `WebBrowser`-based app: `FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN`, `FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT`, `FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT`. You could reuse some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982).