# How can I get the .NET Webbrowser control to always respect the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry key?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

We have a VB.Net CLR 4.0 application in Windows 7 that when you click a button, a webbrowser control pops up and displays a web page. The browser control defaults to IE7 mode, and we need at least IE8 for the page to display correctly (it's an external site that we don't have any control over).

All of our users are on Windows 7 x86 machines, with the following registry key installed through AppSense:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"AppName.exe"=dword:00001f40
```

This works for a majority of our users, but for about 10%, the key just gets completely ignored for some reason, and IE7 mode is used in the control. I have verified that the key is in place on their machines, and that the name matches the executable name in Task Manager, and I have checked their IE9 browsers for any special compatability settings that may have been set in there that would override what is in my key, but I can't find anything out of the ordinary.

Is there any reasonable case that would cause the webbrowser control to completely ignore this key in the registry?

Comment: Check if you see Wow6432Node in the HKLM\SOFTWARE registry key of those users.

Comment: Will do, but I believe that since all of our end users are using x86 machines, this won't be an issue. I'll update the post as soon as I get more information from our techs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (i.e., 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`). That doesn't require admin rights, and you should be setting up this key during runtime, from the app itself. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303), including sample code.

Comment: I'm having one of our techs reach out to a user with the issue and adding the key manually to see if there's any effect. I'll report back once I hear how it goes.

Comment: And months later, they finally came back with a report, and it worked. Thank you!