# Why wpf webbrowser generate script error?

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a site that I am trying to navigate to using wpf webbrowser. When I navigate to it, I am getting script error, but if I navigate to the same page using IE (11) on the same pc, I am not getting any error.

I supressed the script error on web browser, but then some functionality of the web site is not available when I am accessing it from wpf webbrowser.

My questions is:

Why wpf webbrowser generate script error, when IE accesses it without any error?

Is there any free alternative to webbrowser that I can use which has not this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# webbrowser Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call)

Answer (score 4):

The WebBrowser control use an older version of IE.

You need to specify the IE version you want. 
Take a look at this : http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way in code that I can force WebBrowser to use the latest available rendering mode on target computer? can I change the web site so it always uses the latest IE version?

Comment: I was looking for an answer for a totally different problem (Youtube videos not showing in wpf webbrowser) for HOURS.
This has finally solved pretty much all of my problems. Thank you for the hint!