# Windows Forms Web Browser User Control updating in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control, windowsformshost

I'm trying to use a Windows Forms Web Browser User Control in my WPF Application.

```
<WindowsFormsHost Width="900" Grid.Column="0" Height="700" x:Name="WinFormsHost1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

In my code I set the child of the WindowsFormsHost to an existing Web Browser in another object

```
WinFormsHost1.Child = bot.WebBrowser;
```

The Chrome Web Browser here is updating values in a table I need the user to be able to view (and see updated) - but but the other one hosted in my project is not updating, I have circled a value that has updated in Chrome but not in my wpf application.

WPF Application on Left, Google Chrome on the Right

[image: http://i.imgur.com/73tBRu3.png]

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303

Comment: You have Chrome on the left. Can you also test with IE? The Web Browser control is based on IE. So I wonder whether the problem is IE setting or version related. This may be the case if the website heavily uses javascript, etc. We need to be able to prove that the site updates in IE on the same environment as the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you follow Kess and test this on plain old IE first. If Internet Explorer does not work as well then the web browser control is not for you. I would suggest using Geckofx (Firefox Embedded C# control) or CefGlue (Chromium Embed) to display your information to the user.

[Geckofx Control](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx)

[CefGlue Control](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home)