# Set WebBrowser control compatibility mode isn't working

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I need to set the compatibility mode of [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it isn't working. I created the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` with value `9000` and a executable called `contoso.exe` (just like in the example) exactly like [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717055/how-do-i-turn-off-compatibility-view-on-the-ie-webbrowsercontrol-in-a-winforms-a) does suggets. But if I open a page like [this](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/) using the webbrowser it says:

```
Your web browser is:
    Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8
    Internet Explorer 7 Compatibility View
```

How do I fix it? My guess is I didn't have exactly the IE9 version but a high, 11 version. But I didn't find such information nowhere to confirm it.

EDIT: [value 11001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) (IE11) doesn't change anything too.

Comment: Are you also using `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`? More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24569944/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio: The web page I'm trying to open isn't mine...

Comment: @Noseratio: Thanks!!! you code worked just fine. Please post as answer here to I accept!

Comment: Jack, glad it helped! I'm not sure what to post as an answer besides the link itself, so you rather may want to up-vote that link. BTW, if the pages aren't yours and you're into web scrapping, check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22262976/1768303).

Comment: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982 . I've already upvoted, of course!

Comment: Does make sense remove this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the this question isn't exactly a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18333459/1768303), the [same code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303) has apparently helped to solve the issue with the `WebBrowser` feature control (`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`).