# Second WebBrowser control with SignalR freezes javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, signalr

In my WinForm application, I have a "main" .net WebBrowser control with the following JS:

```
var $hub;

$(function () {
    $hub = $.connection.sendHub;

    $.connection.hub.stateChanged(connectionStateChanged);

    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 10000);
    });

    $hub.client.broadcastMessage = function (action, argument, tag) {
        // Do something
    };

    $.connection.hub.start({ waitForPageLoad: false }).done(function () {
    });

    function connectionStateChanged(state) {
        var stateConversion = { 0: 'connecting', 1: 'connected', 2: 'reconnecting', 4: 'disconnected' };
        console.log('SignalR state changed from: ' + stateConversion[state.oldState] + ' to: ' + stateConversion[state.newState]);
    };
});
```

In a 2nd WebBrowser Control, I have exact the same code as above, but if I try to post some JSON back to the server, the page freezes. If I comment out the $.connection.hub.start... function in the 2nd WebBrowser control, my JSON post works perfectly.

Is it not possible to start a second hub?

I need to do something in the 2nd WebBrowser Control, that will update some stuff in the 1st WebBrowser Control.

Comment: You mean you have a WebForms Projects, right?

Comment: No, I have a HUGE CRM WinForm application where several "Forms" now are MVC pages inside WebBrowser Controls.

Comment: @MojoDK, all instances of `WebBrowser` inside the same process share the same HTTP session. Can this potentially affect your logic?

Comment: Besides, I highly recommend implementing `WebBrowser` feature control, check http://stackoverflow.com/q/18333459/1768303.

Comment: @MojoDK: Did you find the answer, I had the similar issue

Comment: @VijayRana ... nope - I dropped it. Maybe using Cefsharp instead of the native WebBrowser control would help?