# C# Webbrowser incorrectly loads html of page

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am developing an Amazon Account checker for a customer, but I have encountered problems in the stage when I need to retrieve order information from the amazon. As soon as the document is loaded I get the HTML but in the orders section I get "There was a problem loading your orders..." whereas in the web-browser it displays the orders properly. Is there any way to synchronize the loading of the HTML (as in HtmlDocument) and the displayed contents? A hint is enough, Regards.

Comment: anyone? why is this question so unanswered D:

Comment: Why is this a C# question?

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler to see if the web browser and your application are making the same requests to Amazon?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, I've done that already. Just for some reason the web browser has to reload twice and I get info on first time, I don't know how to fix this

Comment: @user3788486, my shot at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303