# how to make winforms webbrowser control to work very similar to targeted Internet explorer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

we are targeting our winforms webbrowser control to IE8  with registry key of 8000.

Below are the issues , frequently we face

1. Script errors which are not seen on IE are visible using webbrowser control.
2. web page rendering issues on webbrowser control, works fine on IE
3. Few dropdownlists doesn't work on webbrowser control

Comment: Anyone pls answer my question

Answer (score 2):

1. Try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303) to set the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`.
2. If you have access to the web pages you're loading into `WebBrowser`, use `X-UA-Compatible`:

   ```
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
       ...
   </head>
   ```

   You can also try `IE=EmulateIE8`, the difference is explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx).
3. Once the above has been done, verify the actual document mode:

   ```
   webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(
       ((dynamic)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument).documentMode.ToString());
   ```