# Winform WebBrowser Not Displaying CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to navigate to [Flying Toasters](http://bryanbraun.github.io/after-dark-css/all/flying-toasters.html) in the Winform WebBrowser Control, but the animation seems to hang at the first frame. I am guessing this is a compatibility issue with the web browser because when I navigate to other websites it says "IE7 and IE8 are no longer supported". Why is this happening and is there any way I can fix this?

[image: Frozen CSS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 7 rendering will be used if you do not override the `Feature Browser Emultate` setting in the registry.

For your user (Current User) only use this key:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

For all users on the computer/server use this key:

- On 64 bit app on 64 bit- or 32 bit app on 32 bit machine:

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`
- On 32 bit app on 64 bit machine:

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

For example if your executable is named flying_toaster.exe. You will have to add an `DWORD` entry with the name `flying_toaster.exe` and with a value `11001` (to use Internet Exlporer 11-rendering).

[image]

A complete list of values is listed below (quoted from MSDN):

> **11001 (0x2AF9)**    Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> **11000 (0x2AF8)**    IE11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11.
>
> **10001 (0x2711)**    Internet Explorer 10. Webpages are displayed in IE10 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> **10000 (0x02710)**   Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
>
> **9999 (0x270F)** Windows Internet Explorer 9. Webpages are displayed in IE9 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> **9000 (0x2328)** Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
>   Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
>
> **8888 (0x22B8)** Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
>
> **8000 (0x1F40)** Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
>   Important  In Internet Explorer 10, Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
>
> **7000 (0x1B58)** Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.

Read more about the in this blog post ["Web Browser Control – Specifying the IE Version"](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)

Also look into the [MSDN Documentation about Feature Controls.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will get back to you after testing it!

Comment: It works great, but there are a few things that could be added to your explanation. If you are running a 32 bit app on a 64 bit OS, to change the registry for all users you go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` . Note `Wow6432Node` is different. Secondly, if you want the change to also apply to the debugger, you must change the registry key from `myapp.exe` to `myapp.vshost.exe`

Comment: Nice, glad it worked, and I agree with you comments.

Comment: @Elias, I suggest using `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` rather than `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303