# Angular select doesn't work in .net webbrowser-control

Tags: angularjs, webbrowser-control

Struggling trying to get Angular select working on a page inside a .net webbrowser control.  I have set the registry value discussed here, [Web browser control emulation issue (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526826/web-browser-control-emulation-issue-feature-browser-emulation), to no avail.

I have boiled my problem down to the below snippet, when the user chooses a option from the dropdown fakevalue does not change when the page is in the webcontrol, it works in regular IE and friends.

```
<select ng-model="fakeValue">
    <option ng-value="166">166</option>
    <option ng-value="167">167</option>
</select>         
{{fakeValue}}
```

Any ideas, am I setting up the html incorrectly.  Do I need another directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are capturing & dissallowing the event in Excel somewhere?