# Running script heavy sites like cookieclicker on c# web browser without addons?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

When i run the program it always gives me this message (my computer isn't in english, i used translate so this might not be %100 accurate):

> Command Line Error An error occurred in the script on this page.
>   Line:4605 Character: 4  Error: Identifier, string or number is
>   expected Code: 0  URL:
>   http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/main.js?v=2.041
>   Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?

Then gives this:

> Command Line Error An error occurred in the script on this page. Line:
>   0 Character: 0 Bug: script error Code: 0 URL:
>   http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/ibs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.minute.js
>   Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?

And site gives its own error.

The code is simply this:

```
    public void CookieForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cookieWebBrowser.Navigate("http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/");
    }
```

I did try some solutions like java injection however everything i tried crashed on the launch.

I don't want to use cromium addon since it defeats the purpose of the program which is low ram usage. any ideas on how to fix this? (cookie clicker works on normal ie without problems)

Comment: The WebBrowser control uses old Internet Explorer versions, it's not suited for javascript-intensive sites.

Comment: Oh.. So is there an alternative to this that doesn't eat up too much ram?

Comment: Make a simple change in registry, using these references: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514184/how-can-i-get-the-webbrowser-control-to-show-modern-contents?answertab=active#tab-top). This one is tagged `C++`, but the answer is actually `C#`  [Web browser control emulation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/7444103)

Comment: First of all thank you very much.

The second solution fixed the second error message however site still gives the same error

The first solution fixed everything however now the site has a terrible lag :/