# WebBrowser control not connecting to, or rendering, SharePoint site

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, adfs

I set a .NET `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` control's `Navigate` method as such...

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite");
```

The network requires ADFS multi-factor authentication, and the request is redirected to ADFS login. The control renders the Office 365 "Pick an Account" screen, where I select a valid account and see the message "Taking you to your organisation's sign in page". I hear an audible click indicating the control is navigating to another page. That page is never displayed in the control. The next method does nothing.

```
webBrowser1.Update();
```

The control's canvas remains empty.

MFA does not seem to be an issue. The [BrowserEmulationVersion](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-Emulation-Mode-of-an-Internet-Expl) is set to VersionIE11Edge (11001)

Any ideas why this control is not rendering the result?

Comment: Re-check your Registry settings, based on these suggestions: [Web browser control emulation issue (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/7444103)

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, the FEATURE_XXXXX settings seem OK. We've a load balancer that is misbehaving so perhaps that is the root cause of this problem.  I'll wait until that is fixed before digging deeper.