# How to fix JavaScript library problem on winform webbrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms

I have a library file which named **core.js** . And also a **script.js** *(runner\script.js)*. I have designed an UI with WinForms.This project is a simple JS based "programming language". In **core.js** , I have functions and objects . **script.js** saves text by the IDE and i have linked it and **core.js** in **index.html** *(runner\index.html)*.When i run html file *(runner\index.html)* it works normally in chrome.But when i run it on WinForm *(EasyCode IDE.exe)* it does not work correctly. I have solved CSS problem. But can not solve JS.

GitHub link of project:
[Click here](https://github.com/YunisHuseynzade/EasyCode)

Comment: You have problem when writing to registry when programs start with no admin rights.
I don't know what is you goal, but if you want to manipulate with js and html locally I would suggest use of a local lightweight webserver like http://owin.org/html/spec/owin-1.0.html, and more modern webview like CEF Sharp. This IE control is only trouble.

Comment: My goal is creating an IDE for my own simple "programming language".It gives output to an HTML file.And i want to show this output in webbrowser in winform.And also I have started it with administrator.

Comment: OK, When you test with chrome then it's OK. IE (web control in youd form) is causing problems: you get: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'core.js (45,24). I would suggest to use some other control, maybe chroimum embedded
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: is it possible to solve it in IE? (with any library or module and etc.)

Comment: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103). More options: [Web browser control emulation issue (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/7444103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are eager that this works in old IE webviev control, you should remove default params from all functions in js, etc:

```
function getDate(format="dmy",seperator="/"){
```

should be

```
function getDate(format,seperator){ 
        format = format || 'dmy';
        seperator = seperator || "/";
```

same for all lambda functions, etc:

```
setBackImg:(imgurl,size = "cover")=>{
```

should be:

```
setBackImg: function (imgurl,size) {
    size = size || "cover";
```

and ** does not exists in IE:

```
power:(int1,int2)=>{
return int1**int2;
},
```

must be:

```
power: function (int1,int2) {
        return Math.pow(int1,int2);
    },
```

You could also try to find IE pollyfils for ES5 and ES6.