# WebBrowser in C# winforms lagging

Tags: winforms, animation, webbrowser-control, lag

I'm currently building a desktop app using C# winforms. One of the requirement is to display the client's website on a form, so I've just added a webbrowser widget.

This webpage seems to "lag" a lot, all CSS or JQuery animations seems jaggy. I tried to open the page in IE and it doesn't lag that much.

Is there any option I need to pass to the webbrowser widget to make it more faithfull ? Some double buffering, or any other kind of parameters that I could use ?

Comment: [Web browser control emulation issue (FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/7444103). Note that some of the Keys (as `FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING`) may not be there already. In this case, create them yourself. Use the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` branch. The `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` value to set is `11001`. See also [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103) (for the implementation and other details).

Comment: That definetly helps, making some improvements, but still not comparable to the page opened in regular Internet Explorer, any ideas on what else could be done to improve it ?