# WebBrowser Control with Google 2-Step Verification

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

We have a class library that uses the .NET `WebBrowser` control to authorize access to a third-party API, either with that third-party's oAuth2 Authorization flow or with Google 2-Step Verification (aka 2-factor/multi-factor authentication, etc).

The first flow works fine; the user is prompted to enter their email and password and click *Confirm*. No issues.

However the second flow dies once the user confirms (via their mobile device). The pop-up webpage in the `WebBrowser` control doesn't move to the verified page, it just sits there as if it's waiting for the user to verify.

Our code implements an event handler for the `WebBrowserDocumentCompleted` event and this is fired as expected whenever the page updates. It's *not* firing after the user confirms via their device, though.

I've had a pretty decent hunt around the web and SO for tips on what's going on, and I've also had a look at `WebView2` and `CefSharp` but the latter requires an additional C++ library which I'd rather not bundle or have to worry about and the former is in a very new state of development after having spent several hours trying to just get a basic demo working (and failing).

So if it's at all possible, I'd like to nut out a solution which continues to use the `WebBrowser` control.

NOTE: I have checked which version is being used and it's 11 based on the `Version` property. I'm developing using VS 2019 on a Windows 10 Pro machine targeting .NET 4.5.2 (for maximum backwards compatibility).

Comment: I'd recommend running C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe to view the JS Console or watch network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution actually was along the lines of some other posts, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626667/5818981).

The clue was that 2SV worked fine in the resident IE browser on my machine.

In the end, I added a modified version of the code posted in the link above to my static initialization code:

```
private static void SetWebBrowserCompatibilityMode()
{
    uint iMode = 11001; // Default to Edge/IE11
    using (WebBrowser oBrowser = new WebBrowser())
    {
        switch (oBrowser.Version.Major)
        {
            case 10:
                iMode = 10001;
                break;
            case 9:
                iMode = 9999;
                break;
            case 8:
                iMode = 8888;
                break;
        }
    }
    using (RegistryKey oKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true))
    {
        oKey.SetValue(Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath), iMode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        oKey.Close();
    }
}
```

This isn't ideal as it requires a Registry change but being the CURRENT_USER hive there shouldn't be any elevated privileges required. And I saw that other applications had already added key entries, such as *Outlook*, *SourceTree* and *Zoom*.