# Mfc WebBrowser control doesn't display echart's tooltip when configured use IE11 core，however this tooltip is displayed normally in IExplore.exe。

Tags: mfc, internet-explorer-11, webbrowser-control

I have tried use IECore in lower Edition，then It proved the tooltip can show noraml,but there will be some Js Compatibility  Error.

Seems like some thing need to do about WebBrowser control or Regist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: IE11 has normal web controls that do not respond to mouse movement messages, such as echart's tootip not responding.

Comment: The issue is solved below is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526826/web-browser-control-emulation-issue-feature-browser-emulation?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top

Comment: I'm glad that you have found the solution. You can also put the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to put the solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer.