# 'Script Error' when using the Web Browser control in WinForm

Tags: c#, angularjs, winforms, webbrowser-control

I just deployed a very simple HTML file on local ASP.NET Development Server, with AngularJS enabled in that HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://localhost:30792/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <h2>1+2={{1+2}}</h2>
  <h3>2*2={{2*2}}</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I want to use a Web Browser control in WinForm to open this HTML page. The code is quite simple:

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://localhost:30792/columbus.html");
```

But after I ran the WinForm application, the Script Error dialog occurs:
[image: Script Error]

Could someone please give me some hints about this? Thanks!

Comment: did your 30792 port is enable on IIS?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303