# Internet Explorer font rendering

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, webbrowser-control

I have a simple [web page](http://goo.gl/Oa9ii1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, p, span {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 9pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p><span>Some sample text to show the font rendering</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The web page's text is rendered differently in the full Internet Explorer browser and in a custom .NET application hosting `WebBrowser` control. Both IE and `WebBrowser` are known to use the same Trident rendering engine. Here's what it looks like, tested with IE11, Windows 8.1:

**The Full IE browser** (this blurry text hurts my eyes on a 96 DPI, 1376x768 screen):

[image: ie-font-rendering.png]

---

**The Full IE browser, magnified:**

[image: ie-font-rendering-magnified.png]

---

**The `WebBrowser`-based app** (looks good on a 96 DPI, 1376x768 screen):

[image: weboc-font-rendering.png]

---

**The `WebBrowser`-based app, magnified**:

[image: weboc-font-rendering-magnified.png]

---

Apparently, IE uses grayscale font anti-aliasing (vs subpixel anti-aliasing used by `WebBrowser` control).

**Is there a way to make IE render the text in the same eye-friendly way the `WebBrowser` does it, i.e., using the same font anti-aliasing algorithm?** A proprietary IE CSS setting, perhaps?

Conversely, how to enable grayscale font anti-aliasing for `WebBroser` control, if I really want to?

If someone wants to play with the `WebBrowser` app, here's the source (in C#, using WinForms):

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WebBrowserApp
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        WebBrowser _webBrowser;

        // set WebBrowser features, more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303
        static void SetWebBrowserFeatures()
        {
            // don't change the registry if running in-proc inside Visual Studio
            if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Runtime)
                return;

            var appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

            var featureControlRegKey = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\";

            Registry.SetValue(featureControlRegKey + "FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                appName, GetBrowserEmulationMode(), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            // enable the features which are "On" for the full Internet Explorer browser

            Registry.SetValue(featureControlRegKey + "FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION",
                appName, 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.SetValue(featureControlRegKey + "FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS",
                appName, 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.SetValue(featureControlRegKey + "FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING",
                appName, 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.SetValue(featureControlRegKey + "FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM",
                appName, 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            Registry.SetValue(featureControlRegKey + "FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE",
                appName, 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }

        static UInt32 GetBrowserEmulationMode()
        {
            int browserVersion = 7;
            using (var ieKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer",
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree,
                System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.QueryValues))
            {
                var version = ieKey.GetValue("svcVersion");
                if (null == version)
                {
                    version = ieKey.GetValue("Version");
                    if (null == version)
                        throw new ApplicationException("Microsoft Internet Explorer is required!");
                }
                int.TryParse(version.ToString().Split('.')[0], out browserVersion);
            }

            UInt32 mode = 11000; // Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 Standards mode. 

            switch (browserVersion)
            {
                case 7:
                    mode = 7000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. 
                    break;
                case 8:
                    mode = 8000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. 
                    break;
                case 9:
                    mode = 9000; // Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode.                    
                    break;
                case 10:
                    mode = 10000; // Internet Explorer 10.
                    break;
            }

            return mode;
        }

        // static constructor, runs first
        static MainForm()
        {
            SetWebBrowserFeatures();
        }

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _webBrowser = new WebBrowser() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            this.Controls.Add(_webBrowser);

            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
            this.Load += MainForm_Load;
        }

        // start the task
        async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic document = await LoadWebPage("http://nozillium.com/temp/font-rendering.html", 
                    CancellationToken.None);

                MessageBox.Show(new { document.documentMode, document.compatMode }.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        // navigate and download 
        async Task<object> LoadWebPage(string url, CancellationToken token)
        {
            // navigate and await DocumentCompleted
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = (s, arg) =>
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);

            using (token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
            {
                this._webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
                try
                {
                    this._webBrowser.Navigate(url);
                    await tcs.Task; // wait for DocumentCompleted
                }
                finally
                {
                    this._webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
                }
            }

            return this._webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonathanSampson, are we stuck with grayscale anti-aliasing in IE? Related: http://superuser.com/q/506192/246232

Answer (score -2):

try to use text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;

on your css body

Comment: try to change the attribute value, not just optimize(try others)

Comment: Why don't you copy the HTML from the question to your answer and show exactly what you mean?