# C# webBrowser internet security

Tags: c#, xaml, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with a webBrowser.
I follow the instruction here [C# webbrowser Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1821257) to customize the webBrowser but I have a problem with security, I think.
When my application starts, I have this message in my webbrowser:

> To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this
>   file from showing active content that could access your computer.
>   Click here for options

How can I force the webBrowser to accept my script?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to access the file from file path rather than a web server path (e.g. `C:\path\to\file` instead of `http://localhost/`).  Setup a web server that can serve the file over HTTP.

Comment: Yes, I load my locale web page in webBrowser. How can I fix?

Comment: both options I gave are loading local web page in browser.  One is doing it through the file system, the other is doing it through a web server.  Which are you doing?  Is your path like `http://localhost`?  If not, I already gave the answer: "Setup a web server that can serve the file over HTTP"--install IIS, point it to your path, etc.  If you use Visual Studio, you can just run your site, and it should setup a temp server for you on some port.

Comment: I doing it through file system: I have my site under an HTML folder And load it in my webBrowser.

Comment: So, then, yes, you need to install IIS or use something like Visual Studio's built-in web server that's used when you hit 'Run'

Comment: Try disabling `FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN` and `FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT` (but think twice). More details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx. The author @EricLaw might have a better suggestion.

Comment: @Noseratio I write `FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN` and the other but nothing is changed. When page is loaded, the alert will prompt. I use also `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` : it doesn't show the security warning but makes error in my script that, now, dowsn't work. I very frustated.

Comment: You're setting `FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN` to `0`, right? Anyhow, this works for me with IE11. I didn't try any earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, my FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION is set to 11 but, when the webApp starts, nothing change.

Comment: Maybe I resolved add `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` IN ALL PAGES I use. Before I put it only on the first page.