# Web browser Control loading html with angular.js script

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, controls

I'm trying to create a c# windows form application with Web Browser Control. The intention is to load local html file which is designed using angular.js. When I run the application, I get script error. "Do you want to continue running the script?" 
The files are all local. What's the best way to enable web browser control to load local html files containing javascript in it.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of C# and HTML/JS?

Comment: I found the solution. This helped! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982