# FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION not working for WebBrowser control on other machines

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have changed the registry manually for all the machines. It works on my own machine with Visual Studio. I tried another Win 10 Virtual machine and a Win 7 pro on a remote desktop, but it does not work on all of them. However, I have used the remote desktop to run other exes with similar functions and it works.

I have a guess: does the .vshost.exe should also be added to the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION list?

---

UPDATE: I have noticed the difference of whether the registry key is in Wow6432node according to http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version . And it works after adding the registry key to the Wow6432node. So a new question arouses: When will the webbrowser runs in x86 and when x64? And when will the managed code runs in x86 and when x64? According to my practice, adding registry keys to the path without wow6432node sometimes work and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to verify where it looks.

Comment: @HansPassant In the task manager, the name was exactly its filename.

Comment: Where it looks in the *registry*, task manager doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: @zsf222, try the code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303).

Answer (score 1):

In the task manager, you will see name of the executable file. If you're running the app with Visual Studio (debug mode), the name will be "application_name **.vshost.exe**". In this case, you should name the registry key in that way. Otherwise, use name of the executable file generated by debugging, and run it.