# Marquee tag not work in windows form webBrowser control

Tags: c#, windows, webbrowser-control

I have a url. i want to show in my windows form  webBrowser control. in my html page (url) multiple  Marquee  tags. but Marquee  tage is not work in webbrowser control. it is work in normal Browser

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.Url =new Uri( @"http://67.205.96.105:8080/cis/");
        }
```

This is my url http://67.205.96.105:8080/cis

Comment: I tried your URL with a WPF WebBrowser control using the Internet Explorer 11 engine and the marquees are working fine.

Comment: But when i use same url on any other Browser  text scrolling is work but in  WebBrowser control it is not work i am also try the  WPF WebBrowser control but same problem

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303

Answer (score 0):

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/test.html");
        }

           
    }
}
```

```html
<!--test.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML marquee Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<marquee>This is basic example of marquee</marquee>
<marquee direction="up">The direction of text will be from bottom to top.</marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

Please use the code and try.This code works fine , I think problem is with your html code.

Tried in Internet Explorer 8 and found that your Page does not supports it , that is why you want to edit your html code for IE8 compatibility.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: But when i use same url on any Browser  text scrolling is work but in  WebBrowser control it is not work

Comment: When I tried your url http://67.205.96.105:8080/cis in Internet Explorer v8.0.7601 marquee in this link is not working because new css and html implementations need support for old browsers like IE8 and IE7 standards..NET 2008 to 2010 uses IE8 standards. You may try to re-edit your html  code like example here : http://davidwalsh.name/supporting-internet-explorer