# Audio stuttering while scrolling (C# WebBrowser)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WinForms WebBrowser control in a WPF `WindowsFormsHost`, but I've verified the problem in straight WinForms as well as several different computers.

What happens is whenever a webpage is playing music and I start scrolling the page the audio freezes and repeats the same short sample over and over again. One of the most pronounced sites that exhibits this is [Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/music/listen).

Is there anything I can do to mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling GPU rendering for your `WebBrowser` control via [`FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#gpu_rendering) feature. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303) is how to do it, and there's a bunch of [other features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330733(v=vs.85).aspx) to play with.