# Hammer.js not working embedded in c# WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, hammer.js

***My setup:***
I have an embedded .net Forms WebBrowser implementation, and a website using Hammer.js to enable using both touch and mouse events.

The .net Forms.WebBrowser implementation is default, just displayed on a form.

My OS is Windows 10, so the embedded WebBrowser should work more or less as IE11?

***The Issue:***
My issue is that no Hammer.js events seem to work in the embedded browser (tested using mouse). I have also tested embedding the example page http://hammerjs.github.io/#try-it - and nothing there seem to work either!

Does anyone know why no javascript events seem to be firing and how I can fix it?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18333459/1768303) helps.

Comment: @Noseratio Looked promising, unfortunately did not help, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set a flag in the registry to tell IE (our embedded browser) not to use Legacy Input Model (which, apparently, is default on). The registry key is FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE and more info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330732(v=vs.85).aspx). This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps as much a workaround as it is a solution. But using CEF (chromiumembedded) instead of WebBrowser will work without issues.