# Events of embedded Youtube Video are not fired in WPF Webbrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube-api, webbrowser-control, youtube-iframe-api

**Dear Stackoverflow Community**,

I'm slowly but steadily going crazy.

I am trying to implement a WPF Webbrowser that plays Youtube videos and when the video has ended a C# method should be called.

Unfortunately the events onReady and onStateChange are not called.

Here is the html/javascript that is displayed in the webbrowser:

```
<!doctype html><html>
                    <head>
                    <meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=edge""/>
                    </head><body>

                    <style>
                    .video-container {
                        position:relative;
                        padding-bottom:56.25%;
                        padding-top:30px;
                        height:0;
                        overflow:hidden;
                    }

                    .video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
                        position:absolute;
                        top:0;
                        left:0;
                        width:100%;
                        height:100%;
                    }
                    }
                    </style>

                    <div class="video-container">
                    <div id="player"></div>
                    </div>

                        <script>
                            var tag = document.createElement('script');

                          tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                        var player;
                        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                                width: '640',
                                height: '390',
                                videoId: 'jhFDyDgMVUI',
                                playerVars: { autohide: 1, showinfo: 0 , html5: 1, enablejsapi: 1, autoplay: 1, origin: 'http://www.example.co'},
                                events: {
                                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                                }
                            });
                            alert('apirdy');
                          }

                         function onPlayerReady(event) {
                            event.target.playVideo();
                            alert('onrdy');
                            player.addEventListener('onStateChange', onPlayerStateChange);
                          }

                        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                            alert('onchange');
                          }

                       </script>

                    </body></html>
```

I tested this script on my webserver and it works. But only on my webserver and not in the WPF WebBrowser.

Notice the following call in the function onYoutubeIframeApiReady:

alert('apirdy');

**This is the only call that works when using the WPF WebBrowser.**

But I would like to make calls in the functions onPlayerReady and onPlayerStateChange too but they never seem to be triggered.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303) helps.

Comment: Dear Noseratio, you are a livesaver! I've tried to track this problem down for at least 15 hours, seriously. I will post my full solution afterwards.
I cannot thank you enough.