# How to prevent pasted URLs from becoming absolute?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, mshtml

Having a WebBrowser control, I roughly do the following steps:

1. Navigate to "`about:blank`".
2. Turn on design mode in `DocumentCompleted` event handler.
3. Paste a HTML string with an `#` as the URL.
4. Read the document back from the WebBrowser control.

Step 2 is done by this way:

```cs
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(
    object sender, 
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic axObj = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
    axObj.document.designmode = "On";
}
```

Step 3 is done this way:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
    var selection = doc.selection;
    var range = (IHTMLTxtRange)selection.createRange();
    range.pasteHTML("<p><a href=\"#\">Read more</a></p>");
}
```

Step 4 is done this way:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(this, webBrowser1.DocumentText);
}
```

**What I expect:**

I would expect to get a HTML string like this:

```html
<html><body>
    <p><a href="#">Read more</a></p>
</body></html>
```

**What I actually get:**

I get an HTML string where the `#` URL is prefixed with the current document's URL:

```html
<html><body>
    <p><a href="about:blank#">Read more</a></p>
</body></html>
```

This happens, no matter whether I navigate to `about:blank` or e.g. `https://www.google.com` or any other URL.

**My question:**

Is there any way to prevent IE/mshtml/WebBrowser control from prefixing the currently loaded URL when pasting anchors?

**Update 1:**

A possible workaround I can think of is to paste an absolute URL like e.g. `http://pseudo-hash.com` instead of the `#` and later when getting the HTML back from the WebBrowser control do a string replace and replace the pseudo placeholder URL back with `#`.

Comment: I don't have time to verify, but I wonder if it happens when using `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` (e.g., like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303)).