# C# Web browser invoke click

Tags: c#, web, browser, click

I have a web browser that navigates to this url: https://www.tinglysning.dk/m/#/soeg

I want to automate a search on that by automatically entering text into the textbox then hit the "Søg" button. I do that with this:

```
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("adresse").InnerText = "hobrovej 35 9000";
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btn-soeg").InvokeMember("Click");
```

All that is working fine, the problem is that when the button is clicked, it only shows a loading box and not the actual results

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the WebBrowser control has many security restrictions, which prevents the correct execution if single page applications (SPAs) (like the use of AJAX). https://www.tinglysning.dk/m/#/soeg seems to be an Angular application.

I assume you develop a WindowsFormsApplication (because the WPF WebBrowser does not have the GetElementById functions). I found a working solution, taken of the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1681616

The code snipped below disables those security restrictions and allows the Angular application to work properly. Just make sure to call  `SetBrowserFeatureControl` before initializing the WebBrowser control. E.g. call this method before the forms  `InitializeComponent`

```
private void SetBrowserFeatureControl()
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

    // FeatureControl settings are per-process
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

    // make the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
    if (string.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0
        || string.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0)
        return;

    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                                fileName,
                                GetBrowserEmulationMode()); // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE ", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING ", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI  ", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET", fileName, 1);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS ", fileName, 0);
    SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_XMLHTTP", fileName, 1);
}

private void SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(string feature,
                                            string appName,
                                            uint value)
{
    using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
                                                        string.Concat(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\", feature),
                                                        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
    {
        key.SetValue(appName, (uint) value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
}

private uint GetBrowserEmulationMode()
{
    var browserVersion = 7;
    using (var ieKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer",
                                                        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree,
                                                        RegistryRights.QueryValues))
    {
        var version = ieKey.GetValue("svcVersion");
        if (null == version)
        {
            version = ieKey.GetValue("Version");
            if (null == version)
                throw new ApplicationException("Microsoft Internet Explorer is required!");
        }

        int.TryParse(version.ToString().Split('.')[0], out browserVersion);
    }

    uint
        mode = 11000; // Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 11.
    switch (browserVersion)
    {
        case 7:
            mode = 7000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.
            break;
        case 8:
            mode = 8000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
            break;
        case 9:
            mode = 9000; // Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
            break;
        case 10:
            mode = 10000; // Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
            break;
        default:
            // use IE11 mode by default
            break;
    }

    return mode;
}
```