# XAML WebBrowser emulation without registry change

Tags: wpf, configuration, webbrowser-control

I am trying to render some HTML page of mine hosted on a NodeJS in a WPF app.

I have tried few things and the following option seems the most convenient:
[C# webbrowser Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call)

However **it is modifying the registry** which I cannot (company policy).

Therefore would there be a way to **do the same on the fly**? ie. load the WebBrowser with this setup without updating the registry?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with the XUA compatible meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11">
```

I don't know if you have access to the site's content or not. If you do, then just put in right there in the HTML.

If you do not own the page, there are ways modify the page and dynamically inject this tag with a bit of com interop from mshtml.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore would there be a way to do the same on the fly? ie. load the WebBrowser with this setup without updating the registry?

I am afraid not. There is no property or method of the `WebBrowser` control itself that you can set or call.

Changing the registry keys or use another (third-party) control are your only options I would say.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. Will have to go for a third-party tool then.

Comment: Note: rendering the page works well. However javascript calls are still throwing an error so afraid I will have to go for the registry update anyway