# To change default browser mode of webbrowser control

Tags: c#

I am trying to follow this link [How to programmatically turn off quirks mode in IE8 WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646742/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-quirks-mode-in-ie8-webbrowser-control) to change the default behavior of my `WebBrowser` control but I can't make it work.

I have added a new `DWORD` value in `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`, named the file as `abc.exe` (abc is my application name) and modified its data to 13880 (also tried Hex: 0x1F40), still my webbrowser control is in quirks mode. Am I doing something wrong here?

FYI my application is a web application, not a windows application.

Comment: This does not make sense. How can your app be a Web app? Why not just add the correct markings to the Web page you are viewing to disable quirks mode?

Comment: yes my app is web app and i am using the code given at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net.I have tried adding tags to disable quirks mode but even that doesn't give me expected results.