# For IE10, why the WebBrowser control's default quirks mode is "Internet Explorer 5 quirks"?

Tags: html, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode

From this article [Interoperable HTML5 Quirks Mode in IE10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/14/interoperable-html5-quirks-mode-in-ie10.aspx), the **HTML5-based quirks mode** is the default quirks mode in IE10 for those pages without a DOCTYPE or X-UA-Compatible tag. IE's legacy quirks mode is now referred to as **Internet Explorer 5 quirks**.

In the official IE10, it is. But not in the WebBrowser control. The default quirks mode is IE5 quirks in the WebBrowser control application.

For example: for a simplest html page that without DOCTYPE or X-UA-Compatible tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Get documentMode!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>document.documentMode</h2>
<p>
<script>
document.write(document.documentMode);
</script>
<p>
</body>
</html>
```

The documentMode = 10 in Official IE10, but the documentMode = 5 in WebBrowser control application ( before test, I have added the registry item value: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\MyApp.exe to 10000, or 10001 in decimal).

Why the behavior is different?

How can I configure the default quirks mode of WebBrowser control application to "HTML5-based quirks mode" ?

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you declaring a Doctype?

Comment: I cannot modify the site pages.

Comment: From the article Interoperable HTML5 Quirks Mode in IE10, IE5 quirks mode only used for those pages without a DOCTYPE, and with the opt-in via X-UA-Compatible.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
I think the document mode of my simplest html page in WBC application should be HTML5-based quirks, because it has no DOCTYPE, and has no X-UA-Compatible tag (IE=5) also. But its value is IE5 quirks. Can I have some method to let my WebBBrowser Control application has the same quirks mode without modifying the web pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/646742/50447

Comment: Hi, Rowland. I think it isn't a duplicated question. I have added my application registry key into "FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION". My question is concerned on "why official IE10 is HTML5 Quirks Mode in default, but my application is IE5 Quirks Mode in default". I have no right to modify the web pages (add DOCTYPE or X-UA-Compatible meta tag etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to IE10 web browser control to show page without doctype, you need to set both of the following registry keys to make it work.

**Key**: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
**Value**: yourappname.exe
**Type**: (DWORD_32Bit value)
**Data**: 0x2711

**Key**: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_USE_QME_FOR_TOPLEVEL_DOCS
**Value**: yourappname.exe
**Type**: REG_DWORD (DWORD_32Bit value)
**Data**: 1

Comment: Yes, adding the hidden registry key “FEATURE_USE_QME_FOR_TOPLEVEL_DOCS” works. Thank you for your reply. But there is side effect. The application crashes often after adding this key. Any suggestions?

Comment: @aaron - Where in the world did you learn about FEATURE_USE_QME_FOR_TOPLEVEL_DOCS?  The only reference I see to it on the web is from your post.  Did you raise a support issue?

Answer (score 1):

To force documents to display in IE10 standards mode in a web browser control (irrespective of DOCTYPE), the DWORD value of the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION\MyApp.exe` (where `MyApp.exe` is the name of your application's exe file) [should be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) `0x2711`.

If that is not working for you, I would suggest using a tool like [regmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) to confirm that it is reading your application's registry key.

Comment: I have test the application with value 0x2711. It doesn't work. According to your suggestion, I confirmed with the tool [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) that the registry value was read.

Comment: Yes， the registry key was read。 Is there some other settings to control the behavior?