# IE8 breaks compatibility view if embedded as an activeX

Tags: internet-explorer, mfc, activex, iwebbrowser2, ie-compatibility-mode

Using it as a CDHTMLDialog from MFC, I noticed that for some sites (such as wikipedia.org) the embeded IE reports a `documentMode` property of 7, while using the IE app properly presents the `documentMode` property as 8. Same thing is true for IE11 too (`documentMode` property is 11 when launched standalone and 7 when used embedded). What's going on here ?

Comment: The WebBrowser control is handled differently than native IE.  Use the BROWSER_EMULATION feature control key to set the default to your preference; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646742/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-quirks-mode-in-ie8-webbrowser-control for more info.

Comment: @LanceLeonard That was it!

Answer (score 0):

IE’s Compatibility View Settings determine precedence of how the site is rendered . By default these settings force all intranet sites into Compatibility View regardless of `DOCTYPE`. You can use `X-UA-Compatible` which overrides the Compatibility View Settings, so the page will render in standards mode regardless of the browser settings.
The `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag allows you to set which version of Internet Explorer the page should be rendered as. For example, using `IE=Edge` tell the browsers to render the latest.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Your answer is correct when applied to webpages loaded by IE directly, however, it fails to account for the default differences between IE and applications hosting the webbrowser control.  (These differences exist because it is assumed that applications have compatibility requirements different from the browser.)  Please see the links in my earlier comment for more information.